# Returning array from webservice in Netbeans, .Net sees it as nullable array

Tags: c#, web-services, netbeans, glassfish

So I've created a simple webservice in Netbeans to host on GlassFish.  It goes a little something like this;

```
  @WebMethod(operationName = "foo")
  public double[] foo(@WebParam(name="bar") int bar)
  {
    //etc etc...
  }
```

However, when I consume it in .Net(4.0), it is being shown as a double?[].  **How do I stop it from being an array of *nullable* doubles?**  The xsd it contains the following for the response:

```
  <xs:complexType name="BarResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="return" nillable="true" type="xs:double" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Note the nillable="true"

Comment: What does the wsdl say about this method (and it's return type?)

Comment: To be honest I can't tell.  The wsdl glassfish is giving me something like this: Note that "MyServer" is the name of the service, not the hostname/ip address, and these URLs do not actually exist.<operation name="Bar">
<input wsam:Action="http://MyServer/MyService/BarRequest" message="tns:Bar"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://MyServer/MyService/BarResponse" message="tns:BarResponse"/>

Comment: The wsdl should also define the type "BarResponse" (in the namespace tns). I'm asking this because I want to know if Glassfish generating an inaccurate wsdl, or if Visual Studio is generating an inaccurate xsd/stub from an accurate wsdl.

Comment: Well the wsdl does not have BarReponse defined in it.  The Bar operation refers to them, and the wsdl does refer to the xsd with the definition for them that I posted in my question, but there is no other definition for BarResponse.  But that xsd is being built by glassfish.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with glassfish, but that is where you should look then. Somehow glassfish thinks it should be a nillable element. Either that or you manually change the generated .Net code, risking errors if a message actually has null elements. Sorry that I couldn't provide more help.